# Lots of interviews coming up, should I tell my current place I am leaving?

Tags: notice-period, resignation

I've been working with this small company (4 people inc me) for 2 years now and although I like the people very much, its time for me to move on.

I have had a few interviews so far and a few offers but I want to keep exploring options to ensure I find the right place.

I feel bad booking so much time off with excuses, I feel its time to just say outright that I am pursuing different options and that I will be leaving. It feels like the right thing to do.

But is it a crazy idea? When would be the best time to mention it, I have a lots of interviews next week, I was even considering the full week off, so i am considering telling them today or tomorrow...

Comment: best time to tell them your leaving is when you have a contract signed with your new company

Comment: So do I continue to lie about time booked off?

Comment: You don't have to lie (and you shouldn't). You just don't have to tell them the full details of what you're going to be doing with your time off. They're not your parents, they're your employer - it's none of their business what you do in your spare time.

Comment: @AakashM well we are a small company and chat about stuff, so if I suddenly stop giving reasons or saying "its personal" or anything, it would be quite obvious anyway

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

I appreciate, especially for a very small company that you feel bad about leaving, however until you definitely are (have accepted a job offer with signed contract) then notifying your current employers is a bad idea.

They might be reasonable about it and appreciate the heads up.  Alternatively they might also just let you go immediately, or make life difficult.   You already have offers, but these could be rescinded, so until you accept one, do not mention it to them.

Re- lying to employer.

If you are allowed time off you should be able to take it without a detailed explanation.   However I can appreciate for short notice you might feel the need to give a reason, you can be economical with the truth without lying.   Some ideas can be "Unexpected personal matters" (as personal reasons don't generally require further info and getting a new job is definitely a personal reason)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a crazy idea.

In a 4-person company, you may have a different relationship with your boss than would happen in a larger company.

Still, you have to try to guess what the reaction to your news would be.

If you feel strongly that your boss would just accept the news, then it might make sense to discuss your decision. Your boss may already suspect what is going on anyway. Bringing it up now might allow you to talk about the best way to get the needed interview time off without disrupting the team's work.

But if you aren't sure of the reaction you'll get, if you think that you might be let go immediately, or if you aren't absolutely sure you'll leave no matter what happens and no matter what the counter-offer, then don't bring it up.

Comment: OP doesn't have any offers *that they want*, so that's... one, two, three *four* chickens I'm counting. Before they're hatched, of course, it's so much easier - after they've hatched they're running around, sass a frassing and look, there's just no point counting them then.

Comment: @bharal ... I'm just going to put this out there and can draw your own conclusions https://www.history.com/topics/history-of-zombies/videos/this-chicken-lived-for-two-years-without-a-head ....don't count your chickens after they're hatcheted...